# Change the close link to a hold link

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Now that we vote to put questions on hold rather than vote to close questions, should we see a link under the question that says `close`?  I would think it should now say `hold` or `on hold`, instead of `close`.

The change is relatively trivial, but I feel its significant.  Without it, our change in verbiage is incomplete.  When we still see "close" verbiage, we're more prone to use it ourselves.  It's hard to embrace the new term in our comments or chats when the old one hits us right between the eyes so often.

Answer (score 7):

But you *are* voting to **close**. The closure is placed "on hold" to give the OP an opportunity to fix the problems, if possible, before the question is fully closed.<sup>1</sup>

I imagine there will be plenty more confusion by people who voted to put a question "on hold" and suddenly find that it's "closed". "When did that happen?! That's not what I voted for! Those Moderators have too much power!"

So, obviously, I disagree with your proposal.

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know that "on hold" is simply a veneer over "closed" to make the OP feel less persecuted.

Comment: In asking my question, it was my belief that we're now voting to put on hold, but since [the blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) still refers to the voting action as "closing", I can't disagree with your argument.

Comment: This is very close to what I wanted to say in an answer. The fundamental point that I would make is that when you vote, you are always voting to close a question. You are not voting to put it on hold. If you don't think the question should ultimately be closed, you should not cast a vote. The link is correctly named.